# Trying to run an excel correlation for supply/demand analysis

Tags: econometrics

Apologies in advance for the possibly naive nature of this question.

I'm trying to find the correlation between supply and demand of seaborne world trade in terms of weight (tons) and a shipping index (Baltic Dry Index) that i found. I want to find how this correlation changes throughout the years (from 2002 to present times), and whether or not changes in either supply or demand have more of an effect on the index.

I tried running an excel correlation on both base figures and figures expressed in terms of percentage change, but im getting quite different answers. Would very much appreciate any input on this.

Comment: Those are two different representations of the data so you will get different results, using the base values is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks very much! Any idea why exactly? I've never had any training/exposure in/to statistics so this looked like it would make sense.

Comment: Base values are presented in absolute terms, percentage change is a relative term (it is based on the previous value), this phenomena cannot be captured by such a test.